# nested control is null

Tags: java, javafx, nested-controls

I am really new in javafx development and I want to ask some questions about the best practices and about my issue.

Well I am working ona yugioh! game and I started to develop the interfaces. I tried to do like with react ( working with components and reuse them instead of making interfaces for every case). So I studied yesterday the nested controllers and tried to do as told.However, the subController returns NULL.

Here is the deck builder interface (main interface)

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="controller.DeckBuilderController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="cardBuilderPane" >
         <left>
           <fx:include fx:id="CardInfos" source="CardInfosInterface.fxml" />
         </left>
...
</AnchorPane>
```

here is the deck builder controller

```
public class DeckBuilderController implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML
    AnchorPane CardInfos;
    
    @FXML
    CardInfosController cardInfosController ;
    
      
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            
                System.out.println( CardInfos);
                System.out.println(cardInfosController);          
        
    }
}
```

Here is the cardInfos interface (subInterface)

```
<AnchorPane  fx:controller="controller.CardInfosController">
....
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the CardInfosController

```
public class CardInfosController implements Initializable {
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        System.out.println("init");
    }
```

And the result of my execution

```
init
AnchorPane[id=CardInfos]
null
```

Comment: don't delete and repost a question .. instead edit the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fx:id` for the included FXML is not correctly matching the field name for the controller. The rule for "nested controllers" is that the field name for the nested controller should be the `fx:id` with `"Controller"` appended. You have

```
fx:id="CardInfos"
```

but

```
@FXML
CardInfosController cardInfosController ;
```

Appending `"Controller"` to the `fx:id` gives `"CardInfosController"`, not `"cardInfosController"`.

To fix this in a way that conforms to standard Java naming conventions, you should fix the `fx:id`, not the field name. This will also mean you have to fix the field name for the included element:

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="controller.DeckBuilderController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="cardBuilderPane" >
         <left>
           <fx:include fx:id="cardInfos" source="CardInfosInterface.fxml" />
         </left>
...
</AnchorPane>
```

and

```
public class DeckBuilderController implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML
    AnchorPane cardInfos;
    
    @FXML
    CardInfosController cardInfosController ;
    
      
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            
                System.out.println(cardInfos);
                System.out.println(cardInfosController);          
        
    }
}
```